# MyBatis установка аргументов в SelectProvider

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

Недавно перешли на MyBatis, столкнулись с проблемой подстановки аргументов в SelectProvider.

```
@SelectProvider( type = OrganisationSelectProvider.class, method = "search")
List<Organization> search(@Param("filter") OrganizationFilter organizationFilter, @Param("sort") SortState sort);

    public String search(
    OrganizationFilter filter,
    SortState sort ) {
    return new SQL() {{
        SELECT( "*" );
        FROM( "organization" );
        if( filter.getSearch() != null && !filter.getSearch().isBlank() ) {
            WHERE( "inn like '%' ||  #{filter.search} || '%'" );
            OR();
            WHERE( "ogrn like '%' ||  #{filter.search} || '%'" );
            OR();
            WHERE( "name like '%' ||  #{filter.search} || '%'" );
        }

        ORDER_BY( "#{sort.field} #{sort.direction.name}" );

        LIMIT( filter.getLimit() );
        OFFSET( filter.getOffset() );
    }}.toString();
}
```

При таком обращении к полям аргументов происходит исключение

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$5"
```

А сам сформированный запрос выглядит следующим образом

```
SELECT * FROM organization
WHERE (inn like '%' ||  #{filter.search} || '%') 
OR (ogrn like '%' ||  #{filter.search} || '%') 
OR (name like '%' ||  #{filter.search} || '%')
ORDER BY #{sort.field} #{sort.direction.name} LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Собственно возник вопрос, умеет ли SelectProvider таким образом обращаться к полям объектов, переданным в метод? Если да, то какой должен быть синтаксис?

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Все получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут проблема не в `SelectProvider`, а в использовании связываемых переменных (bounded variables).

Программный интерфейс доступа к БД позволяет использовать запросы с параметрами. В них отдельно передается запрос с обозначенными местами подстановки параметров и отдельно сами значения параметров.

Только дело в том, что эти параметры допускаются не во всех местах в запросе. Например, нельзя с использованием связываемой переменной задать имя таблицы или имя ключевое слово (`ASC`/`DESC`), которое задает порядок сортировки.

В mybatis синтаксис для связываемых переменных - `#{expression}`. В этом месте запроса будет использован связываемый параметр, а его значение возьмется из `expression`.

Для того, чтоб задавать динамически части запроса, в которых нельзя использовать параметры нужно использовать подстановку строк. В этом случае в сам запрос будет вставленно значение выражение как строка. Для этого в mybatis нужно использовать синтаксис `${expression}`.

У вас проблема возникает потому, что имя колонки, по которой происходит сортировка и направление сортировки нельзя задавать связываемым параметром.

Итого в вашем случае нужно заменить `#{sort.field} #{sort.direction.name}` на `${sort.field} ${sort.direction.name}`